# Python selenium driver instance not defined even though instance is returned by method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium in Python 3.7 with Firefox and the gecko driver. I have a method that calls another method to log into a site. The log in method creates a driver instance, logs in, and returns the driver instance. The original method is then supposed to proceed but I get an error `'driver' is not defined`. I've done some research and near as I can tell, I'm doing everything right. Here is what I have, I just cut out a lot of the page navigating:

```
def navigate():
   login()
   driver.get("http://www.example.com")

def login():
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver.exe")
   ...(login code here)
   return driver
```

When calling the navigate method, Firefox opens and logs in fine but when going to the example URL it says driver is not defined. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm not sure why it says driver is not defined.

EDIT: I just found out if I make driver global it will work but why doesn't it work by returning it? I don't necessarily need it to be global.

Comment: Don't post pseudo code and expect us to try to figure it out by guesswork. Post the actual code you are using with an actual error message or at least some description of what isn't working.

Comment: Well, it is the code, just with all the page navigating to log in cut out, as it is lengthy and doesn't pertain to the issue. I probably shouldn't have referred to it as pseudocode. I can see how that can be misleading. I did mention the error, I just didn't put it in a code block: `'driver' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't post your code, it can only ever be a guess... however, it sounds like you're simply not assigning the returned object to your `driver` variable.

That issue is present in your incomplete code that you gave, it should look like:

```
def navigate():
   driver = login()
   driver.get("http://www.example.com")

def login():
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver.exe")
   ...(login code here)
   return driver
```

The change here is that now `driver` is assigned the value of the returned `login()` object. It works when making `driver` a global because then the `navigate()` function has visibility of the `driver` object from `login()`.

Odd that you didn't get/notice a not defined error.

Comment: Ah, that was it. I probably shouldn't have called it pseudo code. It was my code, just with a lot of the unnecessary parts that didn't pertain to the issue cut out. I did get a not defined error, I just didn't  put it on code blocks when I mentioned it in my OP.